# Why is the mass term a part of the potential in Quantum Field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, potential, field-theory, conventions

I am currently reading the chapter on scalar fields from the book 'Quarks, gluons and lattices' by Creutz and he mentions that "The full potential felt by the [scalar] field $\phi$ includes the mass term":
$$V(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+V_I(\phi)$$
where $V_I(\phi)$ includes interactions. In what sense does the mass term contribute to the potential *felt* by the field?

Comment: What does this have to do with quantum field theory? Writing the Lagrangian as $T+V$ where $T$ ("the kinetic term")  is a function of derivatives of the generalized coordinates/fields and $V$ ("the potential term") a function of the generalized coordinates and calling $V$ "potential" is completely generic.

Answer (score 1):

A real scalar $\phi$ of Lagrangian density $\frac12\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-V$ has equation of motion$$\square\phi=-m^2\phi-V_I^\prime(\phi).$$The effect of the $-m^2\phi$ is interpreted as $\phi$ having squared mass $m^2$, but you could just as easily say the field has squared mass $m^2-\mu^2$, then experiences an interaction that contributes $-\mu^2\phi$ to $\square\phi$. The best way to avoid debates like this is to just say that the squared mass is $m^2$, but causes a $-m^2\phi$ contribution that's as much an interaction as anything else. Besides, in more complicated models empirical masses often emerge from another interaction anyway, e.g. in proportion to a coupling to the Higgs field.